# Create a skinned mesh renderer with many cloned rigid objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image: Sphere outline]

I have this code which spawns sphere prefabs at each vertecy of a mesh. How would I make a skinned mesh renderer using each of those spawned sphere prefabs so it fills in the gaps between each spawned sphere?

Basically what Im trying to do is fill this shape so those spheres act like vertices and generate a mesh to encompass it.

My sphere spawning code.

Thank you.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class gen : MonoBehaviour {
    public Mesh mesh;
    public GameObject SpherePrefab;
    private static int sphereCount = 0;
    private static GameObject SphereContainer;
    // Use this for initialization
    private void Start () {
        SphereContainer = new GameObject("Sphere container");
        Vector3[] verts = mesh.vertices;

        for(int i = 0;  i < verts.Length; i++)
        {
            sphereCount++;
            GameObject sphere = Instantiate(SpherePrefab, verts[i] + transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject ;
            //sphere.AddComponent<SpringJoint>();
            sphere.name = "Sphere " + sphereCount;
            sphere.transform.parent = SphereContainer.transform;

        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

Comment: not sure what you're asking. If you have the mesh, just use skined mesh renderer instaed of mesh renderer to render it, why complicate it ?

Comment: Im in the process of simulating soft bodies. These spheres will make up the soft body's outline

Comment: How many bodies are there. I did a slightly similar thing trying to simulate a paper page using a grid of configurable joints, and while I made it it was a tiny bit trickier than I expected (mainly because you don't have control over the order in which scripts run), i ended up grouping them in hierarchy in the order i wanted them connected

Comment: i just saw the screenshot, clearly much more than reasonable to do by hand. I would proppably do something like attach a collider to an empty gameobject in the centre, sweep it and connect collisions

Comment: What do you mean when you say sweep it and connect collisions? How would I do that? Also the spheres are being created at run time.

Comment: There are 515 bodies btw

Comment: it would not be a runtime method, more a pre-serialised order in which you connect the bodies